# execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.FinalException: SObject row does not allow errors

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

I have this trigger to verify this condition , when and status become clos , I can't modifie the object .

Now when I tried to modifie I have this error :

```
We hit a snag.
Review the errors on this page.
Update : execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.FinalException: SObject row does not allow errors Trigger.Update: line 13, column 1
```

The line 13 is :

```
  OBJ.Statut__c.addError('can t be modified');
```

My trigger

```
trigger Update on OBJ__c (before update) {

     Id currentUser = UserInfo.getUserId();
    Id currentUserProfileId = userinfo.getProfileId();
  
        for(OBJ__c OBJ: trigger.old) 
        {
            if(OBJ.Statut__c == 'Clos' ) 
            {
                OBJ.Statut__c.addError('can t be modified');
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: At first blush, this looks like something that would be better to do as a validation rule (rather than as a trigger).

Comment: @DerekF , I tried the validation rule but did not work for me , that way I used the trigger , now the problem it resoled thank to the solution proposed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add errors to `Trigger.old` when `Trigger.new` is available. You can only add errors on `Trigger.old` in delete triggers. Instead, use `Trigger.newMap` to identify the correct record:

```
    for(OBJ__c OBJ: trigger.old) {
        if(OBJ.Statut__c == 'Clos' ) {
            Trigger.newMap.get(OBJ.id).Statut__c.addError('can t be modified');
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your help , I used your proposition and it worked for me